# pass form data to a new window

Tags: sql, pass-data

I'm trying to figure out how to pass form data collected from sql database to a new window. The idea is when the user click 'Rediger' (edit), that a new small window will open up with the current data and an input field for the user to change the data, and then hit the save button for the data to be written to the database. Then the window must close and the original page being updated with the new data. Is this possible? Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you.

Check out the page here: http://kristoff.it/onlinecoaching/coach/ 
Here is my dummy code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getValue()
  {
  var txtfield=document.getElementById(this.id);
  //alert(txtfield.innerHTML);
  newWindow.document.write(txtfield.innerHTML); 
  return newWindow;
  //windowsize(640, 480)

  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="submitform">

<label id="name">John Smith</label><input type="button" id="button" onclick="getValue()" value="Edit">
<br>
<label id="title">Director</label><input type="button" id="button" onclick="getValue()" value="Edit">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some AJAX for this.

First follow [this](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-36165.html) discussion, to be able to detect when the windows was closed.
Then make an ajaxRequest like this:

> $.ajax({
>       url: "someUrlWhereYouCanFindTheUpdatedRecords.html",
>       cache: false
>       }).done(function( html ) {
>           //Some code that updates your webpage
>       });

Note that this code is using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Good luck!